# Can I have an Express server and Java Spring boot for Backend at the same time?

Tags: spring-boot, stripe-payments, web-deployment, nodejs-express-server

I am using Java spring boot for an REST API, using Stripe to handle Payment. To handle the payments, I am planning to use an Express server. Is this Okay? Will I face any issues in deployment?

I am planning to start working on it soon.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple servers connecting with each other via HTTP or other methods

Answer (score 1):

This is really an architectural choice that you can take. It can be justified as being part of a `micro-services` architecture. This is not uncommon, to have different services being developed with different languages and infrastructures, especially when you have different teams with different skillsets working on isolated features/services. There are a couple of things to be careful about though:

- Maintainability
- Interoperability
- Infrastructure
- Security
- etc.

I hope this gives you enough to think about to make your decision.